# USB mouse won't work unless disconnected and re-connected

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, sleep

Ever since upgrading to Windows 10 my USB mouse (Microsoft Intellimouse Optical v1.1) won't work when the machine returns from sleep unless I disconnect and re-connect it.

Specifically, if I do a cold boot it'll work fine until the machine sleeps (in which case it needs the unplug/re-connect routine to bring it back to life) and it also needs an unplug/re-connect if I restart the machine. Oddly whilst attempting to move the cursor doesn't work, the mouse buttons appear to be doing something, as I can bring-up the alt-click menu on the desktop.

- I've checked the Device Manager and "**Allow this device to wake the computer**" is **enabled**.
- The Advanced Power options "**USB selective suspend setting**" is set as **disabled**.

Here's the (relevant sections of the) result of running `powercfg -energy`...

```
Analysis Results

Errors

Power Policy:Disk idle is disabled (Plugged In)
The disk is not configured to turn off after a period of disk inactivity.

Power Policy:USB Selective Suspend is disabled (Plugged In)
The current power policy has globally disabled USB selective suspend.

System Availability Requests:System Required Request
The device or driver has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
Requesting Driver Instance  HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0889&SUBSYS_104383C0&REV_1000\4&24eaae2f&0&0001
Requesting Driver Device    Realtek High Definition Audio

USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Selective Suspend
This device did not enter the USB Selective Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented when this USB device is not in the Selective Suspend state. Note that this issue will not prevent the system from sleeping.

Device Name USB Root Hub
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3A35
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 29, function 1
Device ID   USB\VID_8086&PID_3A35
Port Path   

USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Selective Suspend
This device did not enter the USB Selective Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented when this USB device is not in the Selective Suspend state. Note that this issue will not prevent the system from sleeping.
Device Name Xbox 360 Controller for Windows
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3A35
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 29, function 1
Device ID   USB\VID_045E&PID_028E
Port Path   1

USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Selective Suspend
This device did not enter the USB Selective Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented when this USB device is not in the Selective Suspend state. Note that this issue will not prevent the system from sleeping.
Device Name Microsoft Hardware USB Mouse
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3A35
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 29, function 1
Device ID   USB\VID_045E&PID_0039
Port Path   2
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46499/discussion-between-middaparka-and-harrymc).

Comment: @harrymc Time to call it, I guess - "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.". I'll see if anyone else has any other ideas, otherwise I suspect ali-chen nailed it.

Comment: The message "This device did not enter the USB Selective Suspend state" is utter nonsense from USB framework standpoint. A device can't "not enter" into suspend, selective or otherwise. It is the host port that is FORCED into stopping, and a connected device (especially LS or FS) has no means to refuse this, since there is no specified response to the state change in any way, it is simply a matter of 3ms timeout after port inactivity. So the problem is with host controller status and control port (PORTSC) not obeying software commands.

Comment: Actually, there could be some device involvement, when a device immediately fires resume upon loss of traffic. But I would say that it is very unlikely for such mass produced device as MS mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Proper USB port suspend and resume is a function of USB host controller driver, not mouse. Therefore you need to check which EHCI driver is installed, and maybe try to roll it back. I've seen cases when a software upgrade script would fail to update/replace the USB EHCI driver, and issues will show up.

However, I am afraid that X58 (ICH10R) chipset has a hardware problem with power management. I have an ASUS Rampage II GENE board, and I also have a serious problem with exiting the "sleep" mode. If I force the system to sleep, no keyboard/mouse event would wake it up. The only way for me is to generate a power shutdown by holding power button for >20s. Even after that the system would not start, and only HARDWARE RESET may to magically RESTORE (not reset!!!) the system right into Windows where it was before, just as a wake from hiberation would do. Or might not. It is very bizarre behavior, but I live with this for years now.

Typically this kind of hardware hick-ups are worked out at OEM level via a so-called "[filter driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545890(v=vs.85).aspx)". Microsoft has an official policy not to alter their software to cover hardware bugs, but frequently does so at a request of high-volume customers for a limited time.

So I think what did happen is that the Win10 upgrade does not include the original OEM filter driver, and some power management functionality is now has no workaround. The ICH10 is 7-years old, and likely the agreement to "support" it has expired.

Comment: Sadly no solution, but I suspect this is indeed an accurate summary of the problem. As such, if there's no other responses with a day or so I'll mark this as accepted/award the bounty.

Comment: Why to be so pessimistic? Go back to Win7 and, with original "driver CD", it may work again. :-(

Comment: Did you try to install some older Win8 EHCI driver, or something like that? To have system control, you likely need to either have PS/2 mouse/keyboard, or use something remote over TCP/IP network.

Comment: Pessimism-wise, I think at some point dis/re-connecting the mouse is probably less hassle than potentially having to re-install everything if I mess up a system critical driver and to be fair at six years of age this PC is getting on a bit anyway. :-)

Comment: Yep, this is why I simply turn off all sleep functions in OS, and simply use the "shut down" function over night time. That's why DiY home builds have this disadvantage against brand-build computers. OEMs have to meet power criteria and have means to fix this kind of glitches at BIOS or "filter driver" level, while we, DIY, can't afford this.